# Yocas en Himmel - translation and spelling

Tags: meaning

My German grandmother used to say "Yokas en Himmel" which she said meant "my god in heaven".  I can find the word Himmel but not yokas - would like to know the correct spelling and translation of this saying.

Comment: Welcome to the German Language Stack. Can you please provide info about in which language context _you_ were brought up and interacted with your grandmother?

Comment: Sounds like she speaks somekind of german dialect. "en" is in some german dialects the word used for "in" (same in both english and german). "Himmel" indeed seems to mean heaven here, as it is also used in standard german. I guess Yokas will be the name of here god (in the dialect used).

Comment: I think it's ***Jokus** im Himmel*. It's not God nor Jesus because you shouldn't swear in his name. *Jokas* may be a misprounounciation of the *u*, and German leading *J* sounds like English leading *Y*.

Comment: May also be related to a TV show broadcast 20 years ago: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2193761/

Comment: What region/city did your Grandma come from?

Answer (score 2):

It could be "Lukas im Himmel", which is something my great-grandma used to say on occasion, talking about the apostle, though, not god.
It seems to be a pretty rare saying, I haven't heard anyone else ever use it.

My great-grandma lived in Saxony as an adult, but I do not know where she was born or grew up.

Comment: Would you add information on the geographical and linguistical provenience of your great-grandmother? For me (as a German) "Lukas im Himmel" is something I never heard, even when living with people who are used to maintain close relationship with all kinds of (catholic) saints in heaven and where not and refering to them often in all kinds of everyday situations. This of course is not to mean that your relatives didn't say this anyway.

Comment: As I said, it's nothing if heard from anyone else either. She lived in Saxon as an adult, but I don't know where she was born or grew up.

Answer (score 2):

In Swabian dialect, especially in rural regions, it is still today quite common to call

> Jesses em Hemmel!

(both "e" are short) or

> Jeeses em Hemmel!

(long "e", and sonant first "s") which would be "Jesus im Himmel" (Jesus in Heaven) in standard German.

(For alternative pronuncation *Jekkes* see below.)

Other common expressions are

> Jesses nai!
>
> Jeeses Maria!
>
> Jesses Maari!
>
> Jesses Maria em Hemmel!
>
> Jesses Maari ond Josef!

Not to speak of

> Herrgott em Hemmel!
>
> Herrgottsack!
>
> Herrgott Sack Zement!
>
> Herkules!

where the last three are disguised forms of saying

> Herrgott Sakrament!

I would suppose your *Yokas en Himmel* is related to *Jeeses em Hemmel*.

*Jekkes* is a form of pronouncing *Jesses* or *Jesus* that can be heard in some regions. I remember people saying *Jekkes Maari*, too.

All these exclamations are used to express surprise, either joyful or distressed, or anger.

As for spelling: German dialects (including Swabian) are not usually written. There is no convention on how to spell. Whoever decides to write dialect anyway (usually for humoristic reasons) chooses spelling as he or she thinks fits best. Note however, that "y" in German is never used as you do in English. The letter used for that palatal i-like transition sound is "j".

As for translation: this should be answered by a native speaker of English. Perhaps

> Holy crap!

is appropriate?

Comment: For me, the missing _k_ sound is what makes _Jesses_ seem *highly* improbable.

Comment: @hiergilt  - As I said, you can hear both "Jesses" and "Jekkes" even in today's Swabia.